# Como traer varios campos a la vez con Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estoy tratando de mostrar varios resultados de respuesta.seguimiento quiero que me muestre todos los "seguimientos" con el mismo id de la tabla "caso" , este es el Ajax que utilizo para poner en cada input los campos de la consulta.

```js
function Tcaso(id){ 
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:{'id':id},
    dataType:'json',
    url: uri + "/caso/mostrarCasos",
   }).done(function(respuesta){
    $("#id").val(respuesta.id);
    console.log(id);
    $("#idcliente").val(respuesta.idcliente);
    $("#ncuentaca").val(respuesta.ncuenta);
    $("#nombreca").val(respuesta.nombre);
    $("#direccionca").val(respuesta.direccion);
    $("#telefonoca").val(respuesta.telefono);
    $("#ciudadca").val(respuesta.ciudad);
    $("#nombredecca").val(respuesta.nombredec);
                $("#fallaca").val(respuesta.falla);
                $("#descripcionca").val(respuesta.descripcion);
                $("#resca").val(respuesta.responsable);
                $("#fecca").val(respuesta.fecha);
                $("#estadoca").val(respuesta.estado);
                $("#solucionado").val(respuesta.solucion);
                $("#idseguimiento").val(respuesta.idseguimiento);
                $("#seguirme").val(respuesta.seguimiento);

    $("#modalT").modal();

    
  
   });
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla "seguimiento" que cuenta con un varchar que es el seguimiento y una llave foranea que es la relación entre "seguimiento" y "caso"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me deberia mostrar examplito y big bank

```html
      <textarea type="textarea"  name="seguirme" id="seguirme"></textarea>

            <input type="text" name="idseguimiento" id="idseguimiento">
```

Esta es la consulta de mostrarCasos

```html
 public function mostrarCasos($id)
  {
    $sql = "SELECT c.id, c.falla, c.responsable,  c.fecha ,c.descripcion  , c.solucion , c.estado , l.idcliente , l.nombre , l.ncuenta , l.nombredec , l.ciudad , l.direccion , l.telefono , s.idseguimiento , s.seguimiento FROM caso c join cliente l on c.idcliente=l.idcliente join seguimiento s on c.id=s.idcaso where id = :id LIMIT 1";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $parameters = array(':id' => $id);
    $query->execute($parameters);

    return $query->fetch();
  }
```

```js
public function mostrarCasos()
 {
  
 
         $id= $_POST['id']; 
  if (isset($id)) {
            
   $caso = new Caso();
            
   $caso = $caso->mostrarCasos($id);
   

   echo json_encode($caso);
  } else {
            // redirect user to songs index page (as we don't have a id)
   echo "Error, no ingreso el id";
  }

 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me debería mostrar los dos "seguimientos" del caso 1 en el modal..

estoy intentando con este codigo y solo me manda un valor.

```js
$.each([respuesta.seguimiento], function( index, value ) {
                alert( index + ": " + value );
                
                     });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
define('URL_PUBLIC_FOLDER', 'public');
define('URL_PROTOCOL', '//');
define('URL_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('URL_SUB_FOLDER', str_replace(URL_PUBLIC_FOLDER, '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));
define('URL', URL_PROTOCOL . URL_DOMAIN . URL_SUB_FOLDER);

/**
 * Configuration for: Database
 * This is the place where you define your database credentials, database type etc.
 */
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_NAME', 'segurtec');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Comment: Te has dejado lo mas importante, el código de la página que recupera los valores.

Comment: La funcion ajax es la que lo hace , lo único que no puse es mi index.php que es donde esta la tabla con el onclick a Tcaso  y el modal , trabajo con un encarpetado MVC llamado "mini3" , la funcion manda al controlador y el controlador al modelo , ahí adjunte el codigo del controlador.

Comment: Si, pero necesitamos el código php que hace la consulta para ver el porque te devuelve solo un registro. Sin el no creo que veamos el error.

Comment: Ese es todo el código que utilizo la consulta que puse ahí es otra función llamada "mostrarCasos" y esta le manda por url los datos al ajax , y este los pinta en los input con su respectivo id.

Comment: Vamos a ver, en algún sitio tienes que llamar desde tu codigo a la BBDD, ese es el trozo FUNDAMENTAL que necesitamos. El resto de poco.

Comment: El encarpetado viene configurado para llamar la bd... solo hay que configurar el usuario root y password , pero si quieres pues lo adjunto.

Comment: Entonces ese ¿encarpetado? está mal. ¿Que código tiene la funcion mostrarCasos de `$caso->mostrarCasos($id)`?

Comment: Tanto el controlador como el modelo se llaman igual , el controlador resive el id y lo convierte en una variable y lo manda al modelo este lo resive y hace la consulta por ese id que le mande , ahí pongo la función completa.

Comment: Ves como era necesaria la funcion. Tu problema esta en el LIMIT 1. Con el solo te va a devolver 1 registro.

Comment: Te lo pongo como respuesta ;)

Comment: enrealidad amigo eso no es el problema , lo que pregunto es COMO traigo los dos campos desde el ajax. como esta el codigo  $("#seguirme").val(respuesta.seguimiento); solo trae un campo , mi pregunta fuenta es como hago para que me traiga todos los CAMPOS con ese mismo id , el LIMIT si fue un error mio que lo puse ahí pero mi pregunta es como hago para que me traiga esos dos campos "examplito" y "big bank"

Comment: Quizá esto también sea tu error tener return $query->fetch(); en lugar de return $query->fetchAll();, pues como lo tienes solo te devolverá un resultado aunque existan multiples registros relacionados con tu busqueda. fetchAll(), devuelve todos los registros que tengan relación con tu consulta.

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo es en el archivo al que llevas el ajax "/caso/mostrarCasos" creas el html y luego en el de destino lo muestas en el done o en el success del ajax añadiendo este html a un div "success:function(data){ $("#midiv_resultados").html(data); }". La razón de hacer esto es que necesitas montar un formulario relleno por cada tupla que traiga la consulta en php, y los campos no pueen tener el mismo id, y esto resulta sencillo de hacer en php mientras recorres los resultados. Si no tienes que traer un array con las tuplas y sus elementos y montar desde javascript los formularios.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en que estas usando `LIMIT 1` en la consulta.

Cambia

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id, c.falla, c.responsable,  c.fecha ,c.descripcion  , c.solucion , c.estado , l.idcliente , l.nombre , l.ncuenta , l.nombredec , l.ciudad , l.direccion , l.telefono , s.idseguimiento , s.seguimiento FROM caso c join cliente l on c.idcliente=l.idcliente join seguimiento s on c.id=s.idcaso where id = :id LIMIT 1";
```

por

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id, c.falla, c.responsable,  c.fecha ,c.descripcion  , c.solucion , c.estado , l.idcliente , l.nombre , l.ncuenta , l.nombredec , l.ciudad , l.direccion , l.telefono , s.idseguimiento , s.seguimiento FROM caso c join cliente l on c.idcliente=l.idcliente join seguimiento s on c.id=s.idcaso where id = :id";
```

Comment: este es el primer problema, pero una vez que traiga más de un registro va a fallar cómo se recoge la respuesta del AJAX, no va a mostrar bien los registros

Comment: Exacto , fue error mio lo del limit se me escapo lo que necesito saber es como hago para que en el ajax me muestre varios registros puesto que como lo tengo solo me muestra 1.